# Error Installing Dynet w/ Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, bash, boost, deep-learning

I am following the tutorial here: http://dynet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python.html#windows-python-install
 for installing Dynet w/ GPU and Python.

I can get to the step where I run cmake, and everything seems fine. The issue seems to be building the Python project.

I run:

```
cmake .. -DEIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR=$PWD/../../eigen -DPYTHON=`which python` -DBACKEND=cuda -DCUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR="C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v9.0" -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"
```

which produces

```
$ cmake .. -DEIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR=$PWD/../../eigen -DPYTHON=`which python` -DBACKEND=cuda -DCUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR="C:/P
rogram Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v9.0" -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"
-- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.16299.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24210.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24210.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe -- works

-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- BACKEND: cuda
-- Found CUDA: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v9.0 (found version "9.0")
CUDA_LIBRARIES: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v9.0/lib/x64/cudart_static.lib
-- Failed to find CUDNN in path:  (Did you set CUDNN_ROOT properly?)
-- CUDNN not found, some dependent functionalities will be disabled
-- Eigen dir is C:/Users/pie_a/Documents/coding/nlp/adc2181_h4/dynet-base/eigen
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Found Cython version 0.27.3

--- CUDA: CUBLAS: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v9.0/lib/x64/cublas.lib;C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v9.0/lib/x64/cublas_device.lib RT: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v9.0/lib/x64/cudart_static.lib
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:/Program Files/dynet"
PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR="C:/Users/pie_a/Documents/coding/nlp/adc2181_h4/dynet-base/dynet"
PROJECT_BINARY_DIR="C:/Users/pie_a/Documents/coding/nlp/adc2181_h4/dynet-base/dynet/build"
LIBS="C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v9.0/lib/x64/cudart_static.lib"
EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR="C:/Users/pie_a/Documents/coding/nlp/adc2181_h4/dynet-base/eigen"
MKL_LINK_DIRS=""
WITH_CUDA_BACKEND="1"
CUDA_RT_FILES="cudart_static.lib"
CUDA_RT_DIRS="C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v9.0/lib/x64"
CUDA_CUBLAS_FILES="cublas.lib\;cublas_device.lib"
CUDA_CUBLAS_DIRS="C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v9.0/lib/x64"
MSVC="1"
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/pie_a/Documents/coding/nlp/adc2181_h4/dynet-base/dynet/build
```

All seems good. But, when I try to build on Visual Studio, I encounter 37 errors in  the pydynet project, including:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       command 'C:\\Users\\pie_a\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2   pydynet C:\Users\pie_a\Documents\coding\nlp\adc2181_h4\dynet-base\dynet\build\python\CUSTOMBUILD    1
```

I assume it hasn't work at this point, and proceeding the next step fails, since running the following command gives an error:

```
$ python setup.py build --skip-build install
running build
INFO:root:CMAKE_PATH='C:\\Users\\pie_a\\Anaconda3\\envs\\nlphw\\Scripts\\cmake.exe'
INFO:root:MAKE_PATH='C:\\MinGW\\msys\\1.0\\bin\\make.exe'
INFO:root:MAKE_FLAGS='-j 8'
INFO:root:EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR='C:\\Users\\pie_a\\Documents\\coding\\nlp\\adc2181_h4\\dynet-base\\dynet\\build\\py2.7-64bit\\eigen'
INFO:root:EIGEN3_DOWNLOAD_URL='https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/699b6595fc47.zip'
INFO:root:CC_PATH='C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe'
INFO:root:CXX_PATH='C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe'
INFO:root:SCRIPT_DIR='C:\\Users\\pie_a\\Documents\\coding\\nlp\\adc2181_h4\\dynet-base\\dynet'
INFO:root:BUILD_DIR='C:\\Users\\pie_a\\Documents\\coding\\nlp\\adc2181_h4\\dynet-base\\dynet\\build\\py2.7-64bit'
INFO:root:INSTALL_PREFIX='C:\\Users\\pie_a\\Anaconda3\\envs\\nlphw\\Lib\\site-packages\\..\\..\\..'
INFO:root:PYTHON='C:\\Users\\pie_a\\Anaconda3\\envs\\nlphw\\python.exe'
cmake version 3.10.0

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
g++.exe (GCC) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

running build_py
INFO:root:Building Python files...
file dynet_viz.py (for module dynet_viz) not found
file dynet_config.py (for module dynet_config) not found
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
copying dynet.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
file dynet_viz.py (for module dynet_viz) not found
file dynet_config.py (for module dynet_config) not found
running build_ext
INFO:root:Building Cython extensions...
INFO:root:INCLUDE_DIRS='C:\\Users\\pie_a\\Documents\\coding\\nlp\\adc2181_h4\\dynet-base\\dynet C:\\Users\\pie_a\\Documents\\coding\\nlp\\adc2181_h4\\dynet-base\\dynet\\build\\py2.7-64bit\\eigen'
INFO:root:LIBRARIES='dynet'
INFO:root:LIBRARY_DIRS='C:\\Users\\pie_a\\Documents\\coding\\nlp\\adc2181_h4\\dynet-base\\dynet/dynet/ . C:\\Users\\pie_a\\Documents\\coding\\nlp\\adc2181_h4\\dynet-base\\dynet\\build\\py2.7-64bit/dynet/'
INFO:root:COMPILER_ARGS='-std=c++11 -Wno-unused-function'
INFO:root:EXTRA_LINK_ARGS="-Wl,-rpath='C:\\\\Users\\\\pie_a\\\\Anaconda3\\\\envs\\\\nlphw\\\\Lib\\\\site-packages\\\\..\\\\..\\\\../lib/',--no-as-needed"
INFO:root:RUNTIME_LIB_DIRS='C:\\Users\\pie_a\\Documents\\coding\\nlp\\adc2181_h4\\dynet-base\\dynet/dynet/ C:\\Users\\pie_a\\Anaconda3\\envs\\nlphw\\Lib\\site-packages\\..\\..\\../lib/'
skipping 'C:\Users\pie_a\Documents\coding\nlp\adc2181_h4\dynet-base\dynet/python\_dynet.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
building '_dynet' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Users
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Users\pie_a
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Users\pie_a\Documents
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Users\pie_a\Documents\coding
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Users\pie_a\Documents\coding\nlp
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Users\pie_a\Documents\coding\nlp\adc2181_h4
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Users\pie_a\Documents\coding\nlp\adc2181_h4\dynet-base
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Users\pie_a\Documents\coding\nlp\adc2181_h4\dynet-base\dynet
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Users\pie_a\Documents\coding\nlp\adc2181_h4\dynet-base\dynet\python
C:\Users\pie_a\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Users\pie_a\Documents\coding\nlp\adc2181_h4\dynet-base\dynet -IC:\Users\pie_a\Documents\coding\nlp\adc2181_h4\dynet-base\dynet\build\py2.7-64bit\eigen -IC:\Users\pie_a\Anaconda3\envs\nlphw\include -IC:\Users\pie_a\Anaconda3\envs\nlphw\PC /TpC:\Users\pie_a\Documents\coding\nlp\adc2181_h4\dynet-base\dynet/python\_dynet.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\Users\pie_a\Documents\coding\nlp\adc2181_h4\dynet-base\dynet/python\_dynet.obj -std=c++11 -Wno-unused-function
cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-unused-function'
error: command 'C:\\Users\\pie_a\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

I'm happy to provide more information! A few possible sources of the problem: I installed Boost with pip. I saw a note that the c++ compiler needed to be the same version as the compiler that you install Boost is, but a message on Visual Studio had me install a different c++ driver when building for the first time.

Also, the value of this variable is in Windowese rather than Unix format is this a problem? I set it as a System Environment Variable.

```
$ echo $VS90COMNTOOLS
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the environment variable `MSVC` to `1` and building again. This variable tells the setup code to use settings appropriate for Windows.

Comment: In the end, I gave up and switched to an Ubuntu VM. But thank you for your response. If I feel like its worth the effort someday, I'll give this a try.